# filter rows in group_by up to designated number and keep rest

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr to find when a number in a specific column reaches a certain low point and then remove all rows leading up to that occurrence and keep it and the rest of the grouped data before moving on to do the same with the next group.

Here are the relevant columns and each row is a play in the game:

- game_id = unique num for each game
- team = team that will eventually fall to a .3 or lower win prob
- play_id = num that is increased (but not necessary in seq order for some reason)
  after each play
- win_per = num showing what the teams win percentage chance at the start of that recorded play was

Example df

```
     df -> data.frame(game_id == c(122,122,122,122,122,144,144,144,144,144), team == c("a","a","a","a","a", "b","b","b","b","b"), play_id = c(1,5,22,25,34, 45,47,55,58,66), win_per = c(.5,.6,.25,.81,.85,.54,.43,.47,.22,.77))
```

My goal is to group this data by game_id using dplyr and find the first row which contains a win_per of .3 or less. I then want to remove all of the rows up until that point so that all that is left is the remaining rows afterwards. So for example, my example above would remove the first two rows for team A and would remove the first three rows for team B.

Keep in mind that team a and b will reoccur in the dataset along with numerous other teams matching up against each other.

I was able to get a similar filter accomplished only in this instance I filtered out every row for each game_id group after the win_per hit .8 instead of before:

```
df %>% group_by(game_id) %>% filter(lag(cumsum(win_per > 0.8) == 0, default = TRUE))
```

So maybe something can be revised here to do sort of the inverse and instead remove rows leading up to a point vs after as done with the code above

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` with `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(game_id) %>% filter(cumsum(win_per <= 0.3) > 0)

#  game_id team  play_id win_per
#    <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     122 a          22    0.25
#2     122 a          25    0.81
#3     122 a          34    0.85
#4     144 b          58    0.22
#5     144 b          66    0.77
```

Similarly, in base R with `ave`

```
subset(df, ave(win_per <= 0.3, game_id, FUN = cumsum) > 0)
```

---

Also, we can use `match` here which returns the index of first occurrence

```
df %>% group_by(game_id) %>% slice(match(TRUE, win_per <= 0.3) : n())
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(game_id = c(122,122,122,122,122,144,144,144,144,144), 
      team = c("a","a","a","a","a", "b","b","b","b","b"), 
      play_id = c(1,5,22,25,34, 45,47,55,58,66), 
      win_per = c(.5,.6,.25,.81,.85,.54,.43,.47,.22,.77))
```